# Collision detection between two sprites (without a physic body?) iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am having trouble getting collision detection to work with my two objects. Here is my current code:

```
    _firstPosition = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.817f, self.frame.size.height * .40f);
    _squirrelSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"squirrel"];
    _squirrelSprite.position = _firstPosition;
    _atFirstPosition = YES;
    [self addChild:_squirrelSprite];

    SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:3.0];

    SKAction *createSpriteBlock = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        SKSpriteNode *lightnut = [SKSpriteNode   spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"lightnut.png"];
        BOOL heads = arc4random_uniform(100) < 50;
        lightnut.position = (heads)? CGPointMake(257,600) : CGPointMake(50,600);
        [self addChild: lightnut];

        SKAction *moveNodeUp = [SKAction moveByX:0.0 y:-700.0 duration:1.3];
        [lightnut runAction: moveNodeUp];
    }];

    SKAction *waitThenRunBlock = [SKAction sequence:@[wait,createSpriteBlock]];

    [self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:waitThenRunBlock]];
```

I was following this answer at first: [Sprite Kit Collision Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495285/sprite-kit-collision-detection) but when I set the physics body to my squirrel and nut they would just fall. Is there any way to not mess with the physics (I'm happy with how everything currently works in the app) and just make it so that when one object touches the other the game will end? Is there a way to just set a radius around a sprite? Thank you for any help or information that can be provided.

Comment: How did you resolve this issue?

Comment: I set affectedByGravity to 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Physics bodies are required for collision detection. If you don't also want gravity, either set the physics world's `gravity` to zero or turn off the `affectedByGravity` property on each physics body.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Pythagorean theorem to determine the distance between two sprite nodes. Here's an example of how to do that:

```
CGFloat dx = sprite1.position.x - sprite2.position.x;
CGFloat dy = sprite1.position.y - sprite2.position.y;

CGFloat distance = sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);

// Check if the two nodes are close
if (distance <= kMaxDistance) {
    // Do something
}
```