# How are bodyA and bodyB determined in SKPhysicsContact?

Tags: objective-c, skphysicsbody, skphysicscontact

I have two different fixed SKPhysicsBody in an SKScene.  The only difference between the two is their categoryBitMask.  One has a categoryBitMask of 512, the other 1024.

```
static const u_int32_t kWallCategory = 0x1 << 9;         //512  
static const u_int32_t kStructureCategory = 0x1 << 10;    //1024
```

In my program, I have a standard contact handler called from `-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact`  that begins:

```
-(void)handleContact:(SKPhysicsContact*)contact {
     SKPhysicsBody *bodyA = contact.bodyA;
     SKPhysicsBody *bodyB = contact.bodyB;
     int type1 = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask;
     int type2 = contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask;
```

In my program, I need to determine the contact vector between a dynamic body and one of the two fixed bodies.  In order to do so, I access the contactNormal property of the SKPhysicsContact

```
CGVector c = contact.contactNormal;
```

What I noticed, though, was that the contact vectors were inconsistent and I determined this was because sometimes bodyA of the SKPhysicsContact was the fixed body, sometimes bodyA was the dynamic body.

For example, when a bullet (dynamic body) hits a building (fixed body) from the left, I want the contact vector to be `(-1,0)` each time.  Currently, the contact vector is sometimes `(-1,0)` (from the left) and sometimes `(1,0)` (from the right) all depending on which body `contact.bodyA` is.

My question: given all else being equal (physics properties, etc.) what determines what is bodyA and what is bodyB in an SKPhysicsContact?

Answer (score 2):

After tinkering with several aspects of each `SKPhysicsBody` (mass, friction, categoryBitmask, etc), I've ascertained that the determination between `SKPhysicsContact.bodyA` and `SKPhysicsContact.bodyB` is based ***solely*** on when the SKPhysicsBody is added to the scene

An example to highlight the difference:

`SKPhysicsBody *bullet` hits `SKPhysicsBody *building` from the left.

Case 1: If `*building` was added to the scene *before* `*bullet`, the `SKPhysicsContact.contactNormal` is: `(-1,0)`  Because `SKPhysicsContact.bodyA` is `*building`, therefore the contact vector is *where the `*building` is being contacted from (i.e. the left)*.

Case 2: If `*building` was added to the scene *after* `*bullet`, the `SKPhysicsContact.contactNormal` is: `(1,0)`  Because `SKPhysicsContact.bodyA` is now `*bullet`, therefore the contact vector is *where the `*bullet` is being contacted from (i.e. the right)*.

**Problem**

Because `*bullet` and `*building` entities are added at various times in my program, I needed to implement a method in which I always knew what `SKPhysicsContact.bodyA` and `SKPhysicsContact.bodyB` were and, more importantly, a way to keep the `SKPhysicsContact.contactNormal` consistent.

**Solution**

Determine the `SKPhysicsBody` that you need to determine where collisions are coming *from* and set the `physicsBody.categoryBitMask`

```
static const u_int32_t kProjectileCategory = 0x1 << 1;  //Dynamic body 
//Make everything with bitmask > 32 will be set for the fixed bodies
static const u_int32_t kStructureCategory = 0x1 << 10;  //Fixed body
```

Then, in the contact handler:

```
-(void)handleContact:(SKPhysicsContact*)contact {
//bodyA will be the SKPhysicsBody that was added to the SKScene before bodyB
SKPhysicsBody *bodyA = contact.bodyA;

//bodyB will be the SKPhysicsBody that was added to the SKScene after bodyA
SKPhysicsBody *bodyB = contact.bodyB;

int categoryBitmask1 = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask;
int categoryBitmask2 = contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask;

CGVector v;

//If the categoryBitmask of bodyA is lower, we will get the contact vector from the Dynamic body, which we don't want
if (categoryBitmask1 < categoryBitmask2)
{
    //Since we always want the contact vector determined FROM the fixed body (higher category bitmask), we have to get the reciprocal contact vector in the case that bodyA is the dynamic (non-fixed) body
    v = CGVectorMake(contact.contactNormal.dx * -1, contact.contactNormal.dy * -1);
} else {
    //If the categoryBitmask
    v = contact.contactNormal;
}
```

Comment: This is great sleuthing. Your conclusion that one should always test which body is which (assuming it matters for what your contact handler does) is spot on, but there's an issue along the way: the reason to always test isn't that it's hard to control what order bodies enter the scene in. Apple doesn't promise that bodies A and B will be in *any* deterministic order — you've correlated it to creation order, but there's no guarantee that'll be the same across all devices and OS versions.